# next-auth redirect error api/auth/error 404 not found

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I can't log in. When loggin in it redirects me to api/auth/error. when register, it creates my user without any problem but when loggin in, it starts to fail

Question:

I'm using NextAuth.js, Prisma, and MongoDB. I can register a user, but I can't log in. When I try to log in, it redirects me to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error, causing a 404 Not Found error.

I've created the [...nextauth].ts file inside pages/api/auth, but it doesn't work.
I have set the IP address 0.0.0.0/0 in my MongoDB configuration.
I have added env variables in the .env
I have add the secret variable
I have tried different nextauth file locations
I don't know what else to do. I've tried several solutions, including rewriting the code.

```
These are my dependencies:

json
Copy code
"dependencies": {
  "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.7",
  "@prisma/client": "^5.0.0",
  "@types/node": "20.4.2",
  "@types/react": "18.2.15",
  "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
  "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
  "axios": "^1.4.0",
  "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
  "next": "13.4.10",
  "next-auth": "^4.22.3",
  "postcss": "8.4.26",
  "prisma": "^5.0.0",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  "react-hook-form": "^7.45.2",
  "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
  "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
  "supports-color": "^9.4.0",
  "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
  "typescript": "5.1.6",
  "zustand": "^4.3.9"
}

This is my NextAuth.js configuration file:

javascript
Copy code
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import prisma from '@/app/libs/prismadb';
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: {label: 'email', type: 'text'},
        password: {label: 'password', type: 'password'},
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        console.log(credentials);

        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email
          }
        });

        if (!user || !user?.hashedPassword) {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
        }

        const isCorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.hashedPassword
        );

        if (!isCorrectPassword) {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
        }

        return user;
      }
    })
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/',
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
And this is my login modal component:

jsx
Copy code
// import statements...

const LoginModal = () => {
  // component logic...
};

export default LoginModal;
```

Comment: I would recommend you to not share the actual database connection string as it can be misused. This could help in figuring out what might be going wrong
https://www.sammeechward.com/next-auth-and-prisma

Comment: Do you have the pages folder in the app folder? If so, place it at the same level as the app folder and restart the server.

Comment: Extending on what @NurulSundarani said, you should at least change a password to the database, as the connection string can still be seen in edit history. In fact, you shouldn't share any of the secrets that you intend to use in your app. The same goes for `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` - you should probably generate a fresh one.